# newbie illustrator question : how to create a cut in a shape?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Below is 2 letters where one goes across the other (the O) and can see the small white space between the two.

How can i do this in illustrator, creating the cut shape so i get the white line ? i want to do the same with 2 other types of font but no clue how i do it :(

hope you can help

[image]

Comment: If you just want a white background or any other solid color, you can just set the stroke to the same color as the background.

Comment: problem is i would like it to be transparent :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll be wanting to use *Offset Path* here.

- Type out your characters;
- Choose <kbd>Type > Create Outlines</kbd> to convert them into a group of actual objects;
- Ungroup the group, or double-click it with the *Move* tool (<kbd>V</kbd>) to edit it in isolation mode;
- Select the 'O';
- Choose <kbd>Oject > Path > Offset Path...</kbd>;
- This option will create a second instance of the path, which is larger or smaller than the original; the value you enter is how much bigger (or small, if you choose a negative value) the new shape will be. For now, choose a positive value;
- Click <kbd>OK</kbd>;
- Select both the new shape and the 'L'. Be warned that by default, when you come out of *Offset Path*, both the offset shape and its original are selected;
- In the *Pathfinder* palette, choose <kbd>Minus front</kbd> (the second icon on the first row) or Minus back (the very last icon on the lower row), depending on how your shapes are stacked. If you fail with one option, just Undo and try the other.

This will clip the 'L' shape with the enlarged 'O' shape.

Comment: This is a great answer. It avoids the uneven gap as I did in my answer in a more optimal way.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing it is to do the following.

1. Type out the text in a color that you aren't using, like black.
2. Use the *selection tool*(<kbd>V</kbd>), and with the text selected, right click and choose *Create Outlines*.
3. Right click again and choose *Ungroup*.
4. Move each character into place, then select all the characters and give them a stroke in a another color you are not using, like red, and set the size to the size of the gap that you want. At this point, you should have the image bellow.

[image: Text with stroke]

5. Still with the text selected, go to *Object → Path → Outline Stroke* to convert the stroke, then right click and choose *Ungroup* to separate the strokes from the text.
6. Use the *Live Paint Bucket tool*(<kbd>K</kbd>) and fill in all the parts of the text(the black parts in the image above) in the color you want the text to be. At this point, you should have this:

[image: Filled text]

7. Use the *selection tool*(<kbd>V</kbd>) again an make everything is selected, then go to *Object → Expand* and make sure at least *Object*(if not all) is checked.
8. Right click and choose *Ungroup* until the option is gone, then you can get rid of the stroke by either deleting it or moving the fill to anther part of the canvas.

[image: Result]

---

I don't think this is the most optimal way because I'm still learning illustrator myself, but it seems to get the job done.

Comment: I think you are outlining one extra time but otherwise its a sane although a bit long approach for the problem

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to type out the letters, then "create outlines." Drag them into the places you want them to be after ungrouping and select the O and copy it. After that select both, to go pathfinder and der and choose "minus front" that will cut out wherever the O was overlapping the L [make sure the O was in front]. Then just "Crtl+Shift+V" to place your copied O back into the exact place and shift it as necessary to make the gap bigger or smaller as you want.

It seems to get the job done quicker :0

Comment: Hi Shaku, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: With this method, the curvature of the gap will be exactly the same as the O character, and that looks rather bad.